# Uncompress tar.gz with appending a suffix to each files name

Tags: linux, append, filenames, tar

I wanted to uncompress a tar.gz, with appending a suffix to each of the file name. So, for example abc.tar.gz contains files 'first' and 'second', so, after extracting, if I want to append suffix '.append'the file name of each files should be 'first.append' and 'second.append'. Is there a command or way to this?

Note: Files with name 'first' and 'second' are already there, and I wanted to decompress without affecting already available files.

One thing I can think of is uncompress in a temp dir and then, copy all files one by one. But, I wanted to do it in a one shot, if possible, so that, it will save time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```html
#!/bin/bash
COMPRESS_F=abc.tar.gz
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        COMPRESS_F=$1
fi
for i in `tar -tf "$COMPRESS_F"`; do
if [ -f $i ]; then
        echo "mv ${i} ${i}.orig"
        mv ${i} ${i}.orig
fi
done

for i in `tar -xvzf "$COMPRESS_F"`; do
        echo "mv ${i} ${i}.append"
        mv ${i} ${i}.append
        if [ -f ${i}.orig ]; then
                echo "mv ${i}.orig ${i};"
                mv ${i}.orig ${i};
        fi
done
```

Comment: I think this will work, if files already are not there? In my case, files are already there, I want to uncompress the files at same location with suffix appended and doesn't want to affect the file already there.

Comment: In this case, you should check whether the files are already there to decide to backup them before extracting the compress file. And then proceed extracting compress file and add suffix to each extracted file. Finally, we restore the backup files

Comment: I edited the script to check if the files are already there before uncompressing, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution, we can do this using '--transform' option of tar command, as shown below:

```
tar -(x/c)vf archive.tar --transform 's,/abc$,/abc.append,'
```

this will convert all abc files to abc.append.